# sort data.table after grouping

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a data like this

```
z = data.table(name =sample(letters[1:6],10,replace=T),
Var1=rnorm(10,1,2),
Var2 =runif(10,1,10))
```

I want sum the var1by name and sort the sum like the fake code

```
z[order(sum(Var1)),sum(Var1),by =name]
```

But the code above doesn't work,any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a two step process - i.e. 1) create a `sum` column grouped by 'name' then `order` based on the new column ('V1') and assign that column to NULL (if the intention is to order the whole dataset)

```
z[, V1 := sum(Var1) , by = name][order(V1)][, V1 := NULL][]
```

If we are only ordering the summarized output

```
z[, sum(Var1) , by = name][order(V1)]
```

Or as @Frank suggested `set` functions will be more efficient

```
z[, V1 := sum(Var1) , by = name]
setorder(z, V1)[, V1 := NULL]
```

Comment: You'll need to use `setorder` (or `setkey`) to alter the order of the data by reference, I think.